# c# quaternion reference system

Tags: c#, android, libgdx, quaternions

I'm working on an Android app which extracts a `Quaternion` relative to a rotation, then sends its `axis/angle` representation to `C#` in order to operate a 3D rotation of a vector.

I need this to be done outside `Android` (in my `C#` application), but for testing I'm doing it on both `Android` and `C#` to be sure the results are the same.

The result is not the same, and I noted that the `Quaternion` in `C#` is different from the original one on `Android`.

I'm assuming this is because `C#` and `Android` use a different reference coordinate system.

Here's my code:

**On Android. Quaternion and Vector3 imported from [libgdx](https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/math/Quaternion.html)**

```
Quaternion q = (Quaternion) bundle.getSerializable("QUATERNION");
Vector3 axis = new Vector3();
q.getAxisAngle(axis);
float angle = q.getAngle();
```

The transformation I do afterwards is the following:

```
Vector3 vi = new Vector3(input[0],input[1],input[2]);
Vector3 output = vi.rotate(axis,angle);
```

**On C#. Quaternion and Vector3 are imported from [System.Numerics](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.numerics(v=vs.111).aspx)**

```
public static float[] TranslateQuaternion(Vector3 axis, float angle, float x, float y, float z) {
    Vector3 input = new Vector3(x,y,z);
    Quaternion q = Quaternion.CreateFromAxisAngle(axis,angle);
    Console.WriteLine("Quaternion: " + q.ToString());
    Matrix4x4 m = System.Numerics.Matrix4x4.CreateFromAxisAngle(axis,angle);
    Vector3 output = Vector3.Transform(input,m);
    return new float[3]{output.X,output.Y,output.Z};
}
```

My `Vector3` transformation leads to a different result than the one I get on Android, and I think the cause is due to a different `Quaternion`.

My starting `Quaternion` from `Android` is:

```
x=0.00 y=-0.67  z=0.01  w=0.74

//The axis I pass to C#:
x = -0.00  y=-1.00  z=0.01  angle=83.74
```

While my `C# Quaternion` is this:

```
x=0.00 y=0.86 z=-0,01 w=-0,52
```

How can I get around this? Is there some mapping I can do to have matching coordinates systems? Is there a `C#` way to perform the rotation of `Vector3` from `axis/angle` directly as I've done in `Android`?

I'm getting quite crazy about that...

Thanks in advance guys!

Comment: Well I partially solved by passing the quaternion coefficients instead of the axis/angle representation, but the question still remains valid